# resize an to a specific size without losing its quality in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, cgrect

I want to resize an image to a particular width and height without losing its image quality in iphone.

Comment: can you please elaborate the question???

Comment: do you want to scale up or down or what?

Comment: i am importing images from ipad photo library and displaying that image in a uiimageview. So i want to resize the selected image for fitting it to the uiimageview

Comment: See my solution here it could help you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530573/how-to-crop-uiimage-on-oval-shape-or-circle-shape/10816352#10816352

Answer (score 0):

Resize the frame of the image view that contains the image. The image won't change, but it will get smaller. This way you can use the same image for older iPhone screens and Retina Display screens.

If you want to resize the image (so that it takes up less storage space) you'll always lose quality.

Comment: The best option is to use the property uicontentmodescaletoaspectfit