# How to crop UIImage on oval shape or circle shape?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, ios4

Please give ideas for how to crop `UIImage` on oval shape or circle shape. Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

CALayer *imageLayer = YourImageview.layer;
        [imageLayer setCornerRadius:5];
        [imageLayer setBorderWidth:1];
        [imageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

by increasing radius it will become more round-able.

As long as the image is a square, you can get a perfect circle by taking half the width as the corner radius:

```
[imageView.layer setCornerRadius:imageView.frame.size.width/2];
```

You also need to add

```
[imageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
import QuartzCore

var imageLayer: CALayer? = YourImageview.layer
imageLayer?.cornerRadius = 5
imageLayer?.borderWidth = 1
imageLayer?.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: You are missing `[imageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];` :)

Comment: Yes, You have to use the suggestion by Andres to clip the image to the shape of the ImageView

Comment: As long as the image is a square, you can get a perfect circle by taking half the width as the corner radius:     

[imageView.layer setCornerRadius:imageView.frame.size.width/2];
self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

Comment: I want to crop image in circular shape. So that we can see only circular path and other path remains transparent.

Answer (score 36):

I started looking into this a couple of weeks back. I tried all the suggestions here, none of which worked well. In the great tradition of RTFM I went and read Apple's documentation on [Quartz 2D Programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007533-SW1) and came up with this. Please try it out and let me know how you go.

The code could be fairly easily altered to crop to an elipse, or any other shape defined by a path.

Make sure you include Quartz 2D in your project.

```
#include <math.h>

+ (UIImage*)circularScaleAndCropImage:(UIImage*)image frame:(CGRect)frame {
    // This function returns a newImage, based on image, that has been:
    // - scaled to fit in (CGRect) rect
    // - and cropped within a circle of radius: rectWidth/2

    //Create the bitmap graphics context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height), NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //Get the width and heights
    CGFloat imageWidth = image.size.width;
    CGFloat imageHeight = image.size.height;
    CGFloat rectWidth = frame.size.width;
    CGFloat rectHeight = frame.size.height;

    //Calculate the scale factor
    CGFloat scaleFactorX = rectWidth/imageWidth;
    CGFloat scaleFactorY = rectHeight/imageHeight;

    //Calculate the centre of the circle
    CGFloat imageCentreX = rectWidth/2;
    CGFloat imageCentreY = rectHeight/2;

    // Create and CLIP to a CIRCULAR Path
    // (This could be replaced with any closed path if you want a different shaped clip)
    CGFloat radius = rectWidth/2;
    CGContextBeginPath (context);
    CGContextAddArc (context, imageCentreX, imageCentreY, radius, 0, 2*M_PI, 0);
    CGContextClosePath (context);
    CGContextClip (context);

    //Set the SCALE factor for the graphics context
    //All future draw calls will be scaled by this factor
    CGContextScaleCTM (context, scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);    

    // Draw the IMAGE
    CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    [image drawInRect:myRect];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Include the following code in your UIView class replacing "monk2.png" with your own image name.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"monk2.png"]];
    CGFloat oImageWidth = originalImage.size.width;
    CGFloat oImageHeight = originalImage.size.height;
    // Draw the original image at the origin
    CGRect oRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, oImageWidth, oImageHeight);
    [originalImage drawInRect:oRect];

    // Set the newRect to half the size of the original image 
    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, oImageWidth/2, oImageHeight/2);
    UIImage *newImage = [self circularScaleAndCropImage:originalImage frame:newRect];

    CGFloat nImageWidth = newImage.size.width;
    CGFloat nImageHeight = newImage.size.height;

    //Draw the scaled and cropped image
    CGRect thisRect = CGRectMake(oImageWidth+10, 0, nImageWidth, nImageHeight);
    [newImage drawInRect:thisRect];

}
```

Answer (score 13):

To have imageView in oval shape is not difficult.

You can do the following

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:yourImageView.bounds];
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer]; 
maskLayer.path = path.CGPath;
yourImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

If the rect passed to bezierPathWithOvalInRect is Square the image will be cropped to circle.

**Swift Code**

```
let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: yourImageView.bounds)
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
yourImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

Comment: can i use uiview instead of uiimage to make it oval ?

Comment: how to crop oval shape image for objective c ?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it actually addresses the oval case (and tersely)

Answer (score 4):

**To make a RoundShape Image**

**Step1: in .h file**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *songImage;
```

**Step2: in .m file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.songImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.songImage.frame.size.width / 2;
    self.songImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
    
     //To give the Border and Border color of imageview

   self.songImage.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
   self.songImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:249/255.0f green:117/255.0f blue:44/255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;

}
```

**OR For Swift**

```swift
cell.songImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.songImage.frame.size.width / 2;
cell.songImage.clipsToBounds = true
                        
//To give the Border and Border color of imageview
cell.songImage.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
cell.songImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 50.0/255, green: 150.0/255, blue: 65.0/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
```

Answer (score 3):

After a long search I found the correct way to circle the image

Download the Support archive file from URL http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

```
#import "UIImage+RoundedCorner.h"
#import "UIImage+Resize.h"
```

Following lines used to resize the image and convert in to round with radius

```
UIImage *mask = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.jpg"];

mask = [mask resizedImage:CGSizeMake(47, 47) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh ];
mask = [mask roundedCornerImage:23.5 borderSize:1];
```

Answer (score 3):

**SWIFT**

```
var vwImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Btn_PinIt_Normal.png"))
vwImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
vwImage.layer.cornerRadius = vwImage.frame.size.width/2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only need a perfect circle, changing the shape of the UIImageView could help.
Simply add the QuartzCore framework to your project and add these lines of code somewhere in the lifecycle before the imageView is displayed:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
.
.
.

//to crop your UIImageView to show only a circle
yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = yourImageView.frame.size.width/2;
yourImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: This dynamic answer is a far better answer than the chosen one.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `CGImageCreateWithMask`. Create a mask of your oval shape, then apply it to the image.

Comment: how to separate oval shape on my image?please help me

Answer (score 0):

you should refer [This](http://www.hive05.com/2008/11/crop-an-image-using-the-iphone-sdk/) ...

```
// Create the image from a png file
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prgBinary.jpg"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

// Get size of current image
CGSize size = [image size];

// Frame location in view to show original image
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
[[self view] addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];    

// Create rectangle that represents a cropped image  
// from the middle of the existing image
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(size.width / 4, size.height / 4 , 
(size.width / 2), (size.height / 2)); //oval logic goes here

// Create bitmap image from original image data,
// using rectangle to specify desired crop area
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);

// Create and show the new image from bitmap data
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, (size.width / 2), (size.height / 2))];
[[self view] addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

Comment: yeah you have to make " rect " as an oval... read my comments (" oval logic goes here ")

Comment: (" oval logic goes here ") -this link is not worked. pls help me maulik

Comment: how to implement,pls help me,i don't have idea about that.. i am new in iphone sdk pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 3** answer comes from @Mohammad Sadiq

```
let path = UIBezierPath.init(ovalIn: workingImgaeView.bounds)
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer(layer: layer)
maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
workingImgaeView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, 
Try pasting below code in viewDidLoad().

```
self.myImage.layer.cornerRadius = self.myImage.frame.size.width / 2;
self.myImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
```