# crop image in circular shape

Tags: iphone, ios, image, ios4, uiimageview

I am creating an application in which i am displaying one .jpg image. I want to crop part of image in circular shape. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images2.jpg"];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

CGSize size = [image size];

[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
[[self view] addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

Please tell me to crop part of image in circular shape

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to crop UIImage on oval shape or circle shape?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530573/how-to-crop-uiimage-on-oval-shape-or-circle-shape)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using Quartz Core framework it really has some cool Apis to do that. Check [this](https://github.com/kidsid49/RoundedImageView) `RoundedImageView` example.

Comment: This link throwing 404 :(

Answer (score 2):

Methinks this is a duplicate.  There's an excellent accepted answer in this question, and links to other articles: [How to crop UIImage on oval shape or circle shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530573/how-to-crop-uiimage-on-oval-shape-or-circle-shape)

EDIT: There's a handful of easy ways of going about this.  A CALayer with a cornerRadius being obvious.  But more importantly, there exists the method CGImageCreateWithMask: which can be applied to a broader spectrum of up to and including circles and other shapes.  Note that if your image is a JPEG, then CGImageCreateWithMask will return a black background because JPEG's have no alpha channel.

Comment: If it is duplicate, then you should comment it rather than answer it.

Comment: Shall I edit in one of the answers in the link to make it a little more convenient and acceptable for all, then?

Answer (score 0):

```
        You can use RSKImageCropper for crop the image in circular shape. I am implemented the fallowing code to crop the image in circular shape with the help of RSKImageCropper.

         1. Install the pod RSKImageCropper. 
         2. #import <RSKImageCropper/RSKImageCropper.h> in your viewcontroller
         3. Add delegate to your interface i.e. RSKImageCropViewControllerDelegate
         4. Implement the fallowing code in **didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo** delegate.

    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
        {
            UIImage *originalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
               [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:
                ^{
                RSKImageCropViewController *imageCropVC = [[RSKImageCropViewController alloc] initWithImage:originalImage];
                   imageCropVC.avoidEmptySpaceAroundImage = YES;
                 imageCropVC.delegate = self;
                    [self presentViewController:imageCropVC animated:NO completion:nil];
                }];
        }

     5. Now implement the delegate of RSKImageCropper.

    - (void)imageCropViewControllerDidCancelCrop:(RSKImageCropViewController *)controller
    {
        [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }

    // The original image has been cropped.
    - (void)imageCropViewController:(RSKImageCropViewController *)controller
                       didCropImage:(UIImage *)croppedImage
                      usingCropRect:(CGRect)cropRect
    {
        self.imgVIew.image = croppedImage;
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

    // The original image has been cropped. Additionally provides a rotation angle used to produce image.
    - (void)imageCropViewController:(RSKImageCropViewController *)controller
                       didCropImage:(UIImage *)croppedImage
                      usingCropRect:(CGRect)cropRect
                      rotationAngle:(CGFloat)rotationAngle
    {
        self.imgVIew.image = croppedImage;
        [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }
```

For more info check this https://github.com/ruslanskorb/RSKImageCropper