# Masking UIImage in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, mask, bezier

I have an UITableView where each cell is a picture, name and button, just like the favorites tab in the phone app in iOS 7. And, just like it is in the phone app, I want the image in each cell to be a circle, rather then a square.

Using a program called PaintCode, I have generated a UIBezierPath which I wanted to place over the cell.imageView in order to make the image look like it's a circle. Here is that code

```
//// Color Declarations
UIColor* fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 1 green: 1 blue: 1 alpha: 0];
UIColor* fillColor2 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 1 green: 1 blue: 1 alpha: 1];

//// Bezier Drawing
UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(36.36, 26.36)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(30.5, 40.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(32.45, 30.26) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(30.5, 35.38)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(30.5, 20.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(50.5, 20.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(36.36, 26.36) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(45.38, 20.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(40.26, 22.45)];
[bezierPath closePath];
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(70.5, 60.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(50.5, 60.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(64.64, 54.64) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(55.62, 60.5) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(60.74, 58.55)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(70.5, 40.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(68.55, 50.74) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(70.5, 45.62)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(64.64, 26.36) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(70.5, 35.38) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(68.55, 30.26)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(50.5, 20.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(60.74, 22.45) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(55.62, 20.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(70.5, 20.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(70.5, 60.5)];
[bezierPath closePath];
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(36.36, 54.64)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(50.5, 60.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(40.26, 58.55) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(45.38, 60.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(30.5, 60.5)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(30.5, 40.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(36.36, 54.64) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(30.5, 45.62) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(32.45, 50.74)];
[bezierPath closePath];
[fillColor2 setFill];
[bezierPath fill];
[fillColor setStroke];
bezierPath.lineWidth = 1;
[bezierPath stroke];
```

Simply put, I don't know how to use this code to apply this mask to the cell's image view. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish this more easily by just editing the cornerRadius property of the UIImageView's layer (after importing QuartzCore), and then setting masksToBounds to true. Check out this answer: [How to crop UIImage on oval shape or circle shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530573/how-to-crop-uiimage-on-oval-shape-or-circle-shape)