# how to draw oval shape in UIImageview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to draw a `UIImageView` in oval shape. i try to draw but i cloud not find answer. i show most of round or circle shape.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530573/how-to-crop-uiimage-on-oval-shape-or-circle-shape)

 i try this but this is not work

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`
 CALayer *imageLayer = YourImageview.layer;
            [imageLayer setCornerRadius:5];
            [imageLayer setBorderWidth:1];
            [imageLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to draw an imageview in an oval shape, follow below steps:

1. Create a UIBezierPath using **bezierPathWithOvalInRect**

   ```
   UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:YOUR_RECT];
   ```
2. Create a mask layer by using **CAShapeLayer**

   ```
   CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
   ```
3. Now set the bezier path as mask layer's path

   ```
   maskLayer.path = path.CGPath;
   ```
4. Then we are going mask our view with our own mask layer.

   ```
   YourImageview.layer.mask = maskLayer;
   ```

That's all. Try it.

Comment: Thanks for the post, I am just confused what the variable YOUR_RECT is thanks @Ilesh

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can done it by draw BezierPath but even we can't get exact round-rect image...
so i'll give you other trick...
you use 2 imageview 
one for main-imageview in which you pass your image..
second(overhead imageviw) for  round or circle shape image with orange color border which is transparent in middle/center.

when you use overheadimageview over main imageview then you can find exact round or circle shape image

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a corner Radius half of what your image size is, to draw the cricular.
But to draw oval shape you need smaller radius.

```
CGFloat imgSize                      = 55;
UIImageView *imgViewProfile          = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imgViewProfile.frame                 = CGRectMake(5, 5, imgSize, imgSize);
imgViewProfile.layer.cornerRadius    = imgSize / 2;
imgViewProfile.clipsToBounds         = YES;
imgViewProfile.contentMode           = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
[view addSubview:imgViewProfile];
```

Comment: its not work properly , The shape is circle not oval like above image.