# Image disappears when SetMasksToBounds:YES

Tags: ios, user-interface, calayer

Referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530573/how-to-crop-uiimage-on-oval-shape-or-circle-shape), I'm trying to make a UIImageView display a circular image.  I generated a mask and tried using that image to mask it but that didn't work either.

When I try to mask the image, or change the corners nothing happens.
That's this:
`[proPic.layer setCornerRadius:proPic.frame.size.width/2];`

When I call `[proPic.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];` the image disappears completely.  Same thing when I tried using a [third party library](https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesKit) to mask the image.

Any advice?

EDIT:

```
//Profile Picture
proPic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DummyProPic"]];
//Mask Profile Picture to be circular
[proPic.layer setCornerRadius:proPic.frame.size.width/2];
//With this line added, the picture disappears
//Without this line, nothing is done to mask the image
[proPic.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

[self.contentView addSubview:proPic];
[proPic mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

    make.top.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_top).with.offset(padding.top);
    make.centerX.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_centerX);
    make.height.equalTo(@120);
    make.width.equalTo(@120);
}];
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Your code looks fine, are you sure that `proPic` is declared with a `IBOutlet ` and that to the left (next to the line numbers), there is a little filled circle indicating that there is a connection to your storyboard (assuming that's what you're using)?

Comment: I'm not using storyboard.  I'll see if I have more relevant code.

Comment: If you remove the cornerRadius code, is the image still missing?

Comment: No, if I remove the corner line the image stays unmasked as if nothing was being done to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the .layer for masking to bounds. Try:

```
[proPic setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: Not a method of UIImageView

Answer (score 0):

```
[proPic.layer setCornerRadius:60];
[proPic.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

This works, it doesn't like the `proPic.frame.size.width/2` part.

Answer (score 0):

If `setMasksToBounds` create problem then remove the masking and you can try with following

`proPic.clipsToBounds=YES;`

it may help you.